# Errors when Porting Unity Project to UWP for Windows Mixed Reality

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-10-universal, build-error

I am porting my unity title from the Windows platform for the Oculus and HTC Vive to Universal Windows Platform for Windows Mixed Reality. 
I'm using Unity 2017.2.0p2

It appears there are some libraries that are not being included or that are not supported by UWP. My title will run in the editor without problems, but when I build the game I'm getting a number of errors mostly saying that 'x' does not contain a definition for 'y'.

Here are the errors I'm getting (There are a lot more errors than this, but they are mostly duplicates of these from when something is referenced more than once.)

> Assets\SwarmAgent\Scripts\RingBuffer.cs(184,39): error CS0117:
>   'MethodImplOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Synchronized'
>
> Assets\SwarmAgent\Scripts\MapReduce.cs(48,24): error CS1061: 'Thread'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Abort' and no extension method
>   'Abort' accepting a first argument of type 'Thread' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\SwarmAgent\Scripts\MapReduce.cs(92,18): error CS1729: 'Thread'
>   does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
>
> Assets\PostProcessing\Runtime\Utils\RuntimeUtilities.cs(489,27): error
>   CS1929: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsDefined' and the
>   best extension method overload
>   'CustomAttributeExtensions.IsDefined(MemberInfo, Type, bool)' requires
>   a receiver of type 'MemberInfo'
>
> Assets\PostProcessing\Runtime\Utils\RuntimeUtilities.cs(490,23): error
>   CS1929: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttributes'
>   and the best extension method overload
>   'CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo, Type,
>   bool)' requires a receiver of type 'MemberInfo'
>
> Assets\PostProcessing\Runtime\PostProcessManager.cs(71,25): error
>   CS0103: The name 'AppDomain' does not exist in the current context
>
> Assets\PostProcessing\Runtime\PostProcessManager.cs(80,34): error
>   CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?'
>   because '?' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
>
> Assets\PostProcessing\Runtime\PostProcessEffectSettings.cs(26,41):
>   error CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsSubclassOf'
>   and no extension method 'IsSubclassOf' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Ultimate Game
>   Tools\AutomaticLOD\Scripts\AutomaticLOD.cs(1706,23): error CS1061:
>   'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetFields' and no extension
>   method 'GetFields' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Ultimate Game
>   Tools\AutomaticLOD\Scripts\AutomaticLOD.cs(1708,26): error CS1579:
>   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?' because '?'
>   does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
>
> Assets\Ultimate Game
>   Tools\AutomaticLOD\Scripts\AutomaticLOD.cs(1718,22): error CS1061:
>   'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no
>   extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\SteamVR\Plugins\openvr_api.cs(2984,27): error CS0117:
>   'Environment' does not contain a definition for 'OSVersion'
>
> Assets\SteamVR\Plugins\openvr_api.cs(2984,49): error CS0234: The type
>   or namespace name 'PlatformID' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\SteamVR\InteractionSystem\Core\Scripts\Util.cs(497,9): error
>   CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Process' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Assets\SteamVR\InteractionSystem\Core\Scripts\Util.cs(613,39): error
>   CS0117: 'Environment' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetCommandLineArgs'
>
> Assets\VRTK\SDK\SteamVR\SDK_SteamVRDefines.cs(92,42): error CS7036:
>   There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'bindingAttr' of 'TypeExtensions.GetNestedType(Type, string,
>   BindingFlags)'
>
> Assets\VRTK\SDK\Base\SDK_DescriptionAttribute.cs(141,25): error
>   CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttributes'
>   and no extension method 'GetCustomAttributes' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\VRTK\Scripts\Utilities\VRTK_SharedMethods.cs(471,36): error
>   CS0103: The name 'AppDomain' does not exist in the current context
>
> Assets\VRTK\Scripts\Utilities\SDK\VRTK_SDKSetup.cs(334,53): error
>   CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'BaseType' and no
>   extension method 'BaseType' accepting a first argument of type 'Type'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Assets\Particle Playground\Scripts\PlaygroundC.cs(1798,7): error
>   CS0103: The name 'playgroundPool' does not exist in the current
>   context

Here is the full error log
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ww6ez4O891nSh6HI0CC-Cv6Ex5M6aTBA/view?usp=sharing

I also posted this to the unity forums here is the link to my post on there.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/errors-when-porting-unity-project-to-uwp-for-windows-mixed-reality.508795/#post-3321995

Answer (score 0):

UWP Apps use a subset of the .NET API so don't have everything you're used to available.  I believe this is to keep things minimal for less powerful devices.

Taken from link below:

> Note that .NET for UWP apps includes a subset of the types provided in the full .NET Framework for each namespace

You can see the guide for migrating [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/)

And the reference for the [UWP version of .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185501.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Sorry!  It's a pain and i'm currently going through it too.